# How to get the user's group(s) for sharepoint online site usig Microsoft Graph APIs

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am trying to get the user's group(s) for Sharepoint online site using Microsoft Graph APIs. But I am not getting any equivalent graph API for the below Sharepoint rest API :

**/_api/web/SiteUsers/GetByEmail('xxxxx@xxxxx.com')?$expand=Groups**

I want the sharepoint groups not the AD groups.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

By default, MS Graph API has not exposed such endpoints to access SharePoint site groups. You can raise User voice [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) for the ask so that it goes into our backlog.

Also as an alternate, you can try out the hacky way and see if it works for you.

There is a hidden list "**User Information List**" that stores users (including groups) information. We can get group name through this list.

API end point (GET) - 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{GUID}/lists/User Information List/items?$expand=fields'

Read documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) on API for enumerating items in a list.

Let me know if this works for you.
Thanks!

Comment: thanks for reply, I have tried the above API (User Information List) and able to get the SP groups, but I need groups in which the specified user is present.

Comment: Please go ahead and file a User Voice so that it gets into our backlog.